# Print French in dmg eula osx

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I need to write french along with english in my eula for the software dmg. How do I display an e with accent grave (é) in the eula text file so that the disk images utility interprets it correctly? I have included
data \'STR#\' (5004, "French"), etc. as well as 
data \'styl\' (5004, "French SLA") { etc. in my file. This does not seem to help though. 
Currently, I just have it as is with an accent mark (é), but I have tried to use other encodings. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am using OSX Mavericks.

Comment: What software are you using to build the .DMG ?

Comment: I am using a python script that makes hdiutil system calls. This is followed by the Rez system command:                  os.system('Rez /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.r %s -a -o "%s"' % (converted_eula, dmg_name))                      The dmg and eula are created. It's just not printing that letter correctly. If I can figure out how to attach it, I will do that soon.

Comment: The top half of the eula is as follows. And then the text is at the bottom which I just pasted the relavent portion.

data 'LPic' (5000) {
 $"0002 0011 0003 0001 0000 0000 0002 0000"
 $"0008 0003 0000 0001 0004 0000 0004 0005"
 $"0000 000E 0006 0001 0005 0007 0000 0007"
 $"0008 0000 0047 0009 0000 0034 000A 0001"
 $"0035 000B 0001 0020 000C 0000 0011 000D"
 $"0000 005B 0004 0000 0033 000F 0001 000C"
 $"0010 0000 000B 000E 0000"
};

Comment: data 'STR#' (5004, "French") {  
};  
resource 'STR#' (5002, "English") {  };    
data 'TEXT' (5002, "English") {  
 "IMPORTANT-READ CAREFULLY: THE TERMS OF THIS END USER\n" <br/>Les parties ont demandé que cette convention\n"
 "ainsi que tous les documents qui s'y rattachent soient\n"
 "rédigés en anglais.\n".............

Comment: So sorry for the bad formatting. It looks like syntax errors, but it's really not. Now I am wondering if the problem is that I have data 'TEXT' (5002, "English") and since there is also French, it won't read it. How do I add multiple languages in that line?

Comment: So I tried changing the data 'TEXT' (5002, "English") to data 'TEXT' (5004, "French") and that didn't solve it. Though another portion automatically changed to French and those special characters with accent marks are correctly printed. I think it's just a matter of encoding, but I don't know where or which encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Your example was like this.  I had to extract it from a comment because it was missing from the question, and I filled in context which is apparently missing.

```
data 'TEXT' (5002, "English") {
    "IMPORTANT-READ CAREFULLY: THE TERMS OF THIS END USER\n"
    <br/>Les parties ont demandé que cette convention\n"
    "ainsi que tous les documents qui s'y rattachent soient\n"
    "rédigés en anglais.\n".
    ...
};
```

Whereas text may work here as well (I wasn't aware of it until now), what we have in our own is in encoded binary:

```
data 'TEXT' (5000, "English SLA") {
    $"596f 7572 2075 7361 6765 206f 6620 7468"
    $"6973 2073 6f66 7477 6172 6520 6973 2067"
    ...
```

My guess is that your accented character went into your file as UTF-8. I would figure out what encoding English uses on OSX (I think it's MacRoman), encode your text in that encoding and then encode that as hex in this fashion, and that should work.